# Extracting bond information from the xyz positions of atoms?

Tags: software, lammps, vmd

I have xyz positions of my atoms in a `.txt` file, how can I extract  information about bonding using VMD?

I want to create a LAMMPS input file that contains not only the positions, but also information about the bonding of the structure.

Answer (score 6):

This seems to be what the [TopoTools](https://www.ks.uiuc.edu/Research/vmd/plugins/topotools/) plugin is used for. This has commands for manipulating bonds/angles/dihedrals in VMD and then writing the corresponding information to a LAMMPS input file.

Comment: Thank you Tyberius, I am using topotools to read the xyz data by command "mol new" and then using the command "retype bonds" to get the bonding structure but I get the error there are more than 12 bonds ...

Comment: @DelaramNematollahi [This thread](https://www.ks.uiuc.edu/Research/vmd/mailing_list/vmd-l/27438.html) seems to be related. It seems like for your molecule this is trying to add 12 bonds around a single atom (or possibly several atoms).  VMD doesn't set a limit on the total number of bonds, but depending the on the compiled version, it typically doesn't allow more than 12 bonds around an atom.

Comment: thanks a lot. in my file I do not have any bonding . I just have the x y z positions of atoms. basically I am looking for a way to or a command that can create the bonds between nearest neighbours and give me the bond information